# How to call this type of methods in java in a different class?

Tags: java

```
public class CourseManagerPage extends MathPage{

public CourseSettingsSummaryPage clickCourseSettings(String courseName) {}
```

}

I want to call "clickCourseSettings" method in another class called "TestClass". (Note:- In here CourseSettingsSummaryPage also a class).How can i do that?

Comment: `objectName.clickCourseSettings("foo")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class that will call this method need to have a **CourseManagerPage** object.

```
class OtherClass {
   public void otherMethod() {
     CourseManagerPage cmp = new CourseManagerPage();
     CourseSettingsSummaryPage ret = cmp.clickCourseSettings("param");
   }
}
```

The **new CourseManagerPage()**, doesn't need to be precisely there, but it is needed, and must be executed before the method call.